# Dynamically created A-FRAME content set to embedded will not show A-FRAME inspector

Tags: aframe

I'm creating A-FRAME scenes dynamically with a function that takes a image path as an argument and returns a built A-FRAME a-scene.

The returned value is working and appearing correctly in the DOM though attempting to initialize the A-FRAME inspector with ctrl + alt + i does not work, mainly due to the dynamically appended content.

Is there a flag or setting within A-FRAME to allow for the inspector to work with dynamically appended content or other such workaround?

```
     function buildCelestialBody(a) {
    let aframe= `
                <!-- AFRAME CONTENT -->
                <!-- MAIN SCENE -->
                <a-scene embedded
                        loading-screen="dotsColor: #ffffff;  backgroundColor: black;"
                        vr-mode-ui="enabled: false fuseTimeout: 0">

                    <!-- ASSETS -->
                    <a-assets>
                        <img id="celestialbody" src="${a}"></img>
                    </a-assets>

                    <!-- CAMERA -->
                    <a-entity id='cameraWrapper' position="0 0 0" rotation="0 0 0">
                        <a-camera id="camera1" camera="active: true; zoom: 3.5;
                        spectator: false;"
                        look-controls="enabled:  false"></a-camera>
                    </a-entity>

                    <!-- CELESTIAL BODY -->
                    <a-sphere src="#celestialbody"
                    geometry="primitive: sphere;
                              segmentsHeight: 100;
                              segmentsWidth: 100"
                    scale="1 1 1"
                    position="0 0 -8.5;"
                    animation="property: rotation;
                                dur: 200000;
                                from: 400 360 0;
                                to: 400 -360 0;
                                dir: reverse;
                                loop: true;
                                easing: linear"
                    id="celestialbody" celestialbody>
                    </a-sphere>

                    <!-- LIGHT -->
                    <a-entity id="light"
                              light="type:directional; castShadow:true;"
                              position="2 1 1"
                              animation="property: position;
                                        dur: 2000;
                                        from: 2 1 1;
                                        to: -2 1 1;
                                        dir: reverse;
                                        loop: true;
                                        autoplay: false;
                                        easing: easeInQuad;">
                    </a-entity>

                </a-entity>

                <!-- LIGHT SOURCES -->
                <a-light id="light_1" type="ambient" color="#9ecdf9" intensity="0.460" position="2 4 4"></a-light>

                </a-scene>

                <!-- AFRAME CONTENT END -->`
        return aframe;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your creation code within a component, not simply a globally scoped function. Placing it within a component insures that everything( inlcuding the inspector) is loaded first, then your code runs, and the objects will be registered by the inspector.

```
        AFRAME.registerComponent('treeman', {
            init: function(){
                let el = this.el;
                let sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
                let trees = sceneEl.querySelector('#trees');
                el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e =>{
                    //trees.emit('modelisloaded');
                    let tree3D = el.getObject3D('mesh');
                    if (!tree3D){return;}                   
                    tree3D.traverse(function(node){
                        if (node.isMesh){                           
                            node.renderOrder = 2;
                            console.log(node.name, node.renderOrder, node.material);
                            node.material.color=new THREE.Color(0xaa5522);
                            node.material.map = null;
                        }
                    });

                    let countX = 10;
                    let cubes = [];
                    let size = 0.125, spacing = 0.05, x;
                    for (let i=0; i<countX; i++){
                      cubes[i] = document.createElement('a-entity'); // create the element
                       // create components, id, geometry, position
                      cubes[i].setAttribute('id', 'tree_'+i.toString());
                      cubes[i].setAttribute('gltf-model', '#tree');
                      x = (size + spacing) * countX * (-0.5) + i * (size + spacing) ;
                      y = Math.random() * 0.25;
                      z = Math.random() * 1;
                      cubes[i].setAttribute('position', x.toString()+ ' '+y.toString()+' '+z.toString() );


                      // you can add event listeners here for interaction, such as mouse events.
                      sceneEl.appendChild(cubes[i]);// Append the element to the scene, so it becomes part of the DOM.
                    }           
              });
            }
        });


       <a-entity id="treemodel" visible="false" gltf-model="#tree" scale="5 5 5" treeman></a-entity>
```

I just ran this an confirmed that the dynamically created objects do appear within the inspector.

[glitch here](https://glitch.com/~tree-grove)

Comment: The <a-entity> I am assuming is already existing in the DOM? I have tried the above but the <a-entity> in my use case is created via JavaScript then appended dynamically to the dom below the body. Even with the registered component, I am not able to initialize the a-frame inspector and this has to do with what you mentioned, the inspector may be loading but the timing of the element being appended to the dom is causing it to fail.

Comment: Your code structure is very unusual, in the way it places html calls inside javascript. I am surprised this works at all. Your html should be within the body tags, and the javascript all within the script tags. I am suggesting that you should reconsider the way that you 'dynamically create elements', and use THREEjs commands and Aframe commands within js scripts to create the entities. Ultimately the entities are js, so its best to use js to create them.

Comment: Aframe has come up with a clever way to embed components within html, but it is syntactic sugar (a coding convenience). You can create 3D elements manually inside html. But you must use components to modify them, otherwise you run into errors based on js running before the aframe scene is loaded and ready.

Comment: The code structure is akin to the likes of https://www.codereadability.com/constructing-html-with-templates/. Registering the component as you suggested is great as one can call AFRAME.components.foo in the console log and proceed, whereas the initial attempt above still shows the a-scene but is not registered within a-frame if called in the console. However, unless there is a <a-scene></a-scene> already in the markup and not appended to the DOM via JS, the inspector will not load, registered or not. It may be a case of using AFRAME in a manner other than intended.

Comment: You can have a simple scene declaration with an emtpy entity that contains the component that then generates all the other entities. ```<a-scene> <a-entity component-manager ></a-entity></a-scene>```   This is what the glitch above is doing with ```tree-manager```